# How do I access loopback data in the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, loopbackjs

I am currently using loopback (http://loopback.io/) to run an application, while most of the data is accessed on the front end using the angular SDK I also have a socket connection where I'd like to access this data.

In server/server.js I've got

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var app = module.exports = loopback();

if (require.main === module) {
    //app.start();
    app.io = require('socket.io')(app.start());
    app.io.on('connection', gameControl.onConnect);
}
```

Which runs the following in server/controllers/gameController.js

```
exports.onConnect = function(socket) { ... }
```

In this file I'd like to call my models, something like

```
Users.find({}, function(res) {
    //Do some stuff
});
```

How do I do this? I don't know what to 'require' :/

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model.find({where: {name: 'John', functoin(err, models)...` is an example.

See more at http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+data#Queryingdata-Nodesyntax

Comment: So I did that

"Student.find({where: {username: 'DarylR'}}, function(err, models) {
 console.log('hey')
})"

but that comes up with 

"ReferenceError: Student is not defined"

As for the documentation, I understand that is the code you write, but I dont think I have the right dependencies.

Comment: Where are you writing this code? Is this in a boot script? Anywhere you can access the `app` object, you can access models via `app.models.Student`.